# Transpose rows(one column value) into column in mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot-table, transpose

I have written query in mariadb to get some result. result is as follows

```
paracode paramname paramrange value
0010      Test      10-50       20
0010      Test      10-50       30
0010      Test      10-50       15
0020      Test2     0-100       20
0020      Test2     0-100       50
```

I want to display the result as

```
0010     Test      10-20     20     30      15
0020     Test2     0-100     20     50
```

My query is as follow

```
select transquantity_parameter paramcode, concat(transquantity_parameter,'-',parameter_name) pramName,transquantity_value 
         from pkgqc_transquantity inner join pkgqc_itemparameter ON parameter_code = transquantity_parameter 
         WHERE transquantity_headerno ='9405000143' and transquantity_type ='QN'
order by 1
```

Comment: queries cannot return a variable number of columns; you need to specify some other way you want the multiple values returned

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  See the [pivot-table] tag.

Plan B:  Use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.